# AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.GWidget()

window.show()
```

Podrían decirme por qué sale este error, por favor.

```
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QApplication'
```

Answer (score 2):

La API ha cambiado en PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

# ...

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
```